# JPA: Load list of values from another table

Tags: java, jpa, entity-relationship

I've got 2 tables `vehicle` and `vehicle_image`. The vehicle table contains all master data of the vehicles and the vehicle_image table contains the meta information of the images and the Base64 encoded string of the image. On vehicle may have 0 or more images.

Now when I query the vehicle object I'd like the object to contain the information from the vehicle_image table.

I'm pretty new to JPA and the examples I could find always seem to read only one value from another table, not a list.

What would be the simplest way of adding an attribute to the vehicle object that contains the image data?

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "vehicle")
public class Vehicle {
  @Id
  private String vin;
  private String commission;
  @Column(name="swiss_type_number")
  private String swissTypeNumber;
  @Column(name="sale_type")
  private String saleType;
  @Column(name="exterior_color")
  private String exteriorColor;
  @Column(name="interior_color")
  private String interiorColor;
  private String remarks;
  @Column(name="additional_title")
  private String additionalTitle;
  @Column(name="added_value_description")
  private String addedValueDescription;
  @Column(name="first_registration")
  private String firstRegistration;
  private String guaranty; 
  @Column(name="last_inspection")
  private String lastInspection;

  private int dealer;
  private int mileage;
  private int price;
  private int seats;
  @Column(name="model_year")
  private int modelYear;

  @Column(name="car_damaged_in_accident")
  private boolean carDamagedInAccident;
  private boolean imported;

  // List of images
  List<VehicleImage> vehicleImages; // Something like this would be nice
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPA supports associations between entities. The one you need is [@OneToMany](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html)
If your `vehicle_image' table contains column`vehicle_id`you will need following mapping in`Vehicle` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE")
@XmlRootElement(name = "vehicle")
public class Vehicle {

    // other fields here

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vehicle")
    Set<VehicleImage> vehicleImages;

}
```

And also this in `VehicleImage`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE_IMAGE")
public class VehicleImage{

    // other fields here

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="VEHICLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    Vehicle vehicle;

}
```

Also you should better use `Set` for collections mapping in JPA, but it is a different topic

Comment: Is the `VehicleImage` class supposed to contain an instance of itstelf? Or were you trying to reference the `Vehicle` class?

Comment: I had to switch to `FetchType.EAGER` and didn't had to use the `@JoinColumn` annotation, but apart from that it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a [one-to-may](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) relationship, you can use:

```
@OneToMany
List<VehicleImage> vehicleImages;
```

Refere to the javadoc for the attributes it may take and add them according to your table definitions.

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) you can find some examples of how to use it.